# Combine data file and label file together to have one single labelled dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, purrr, r-haven

I have two data frames, one is survey data (data.csv) and another one is label data (label.csv). Here is the sample data (My original data has about 150 variables)

```
#sample data

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~House_member, ~dob, ~age_quota, ~work, ~sex, ~pss,
  1L,            4L,  1983L,  2L,        2L,     1,      1,
  2L,            1L,  1940L,  7L,        2L,     1,      2,
  3L,            2L,  1951L,  5L,        6L,     1,      1,
  4L,            4L,  1965L,  2L,        2L,     1,      4,
  5L,            3L,  1965L,  2L,        3L,     1,      1,
  6L,            1L,  1951L,  3L,        1L,     1,      3,
  7L,            1L,  1955L,  1L,        1L,     1,      3,
  8L,            4L,  1982L,  2L,        2L,     2,      5,
  9L,            2L,  1990L,  2L,        4L,     2,      3,
  10L,            2L,  1953L, 3L,        2L,     2,      4
)


#sample label data
label <- tibble::tribble(
                ~variable, ~value,                           ~label,
           "House_member",     NA, "How many people live with you?",
           "House_member",     1L,                       "1 person",
           "House_member",     2L,                      "2 persons",
           "House_member",     3L,                      "3 persons",
           "House_member",     4L,                      "4 persons",
           "House_member",     5L,                      "5 persons",
           "House_member",     6L,                      "6 persons",
           "House_member",     7L,                      "7 persons",
           "House_member",     8L,                      "8 persons",
           "House_member",     9L,                      "9 persons",
           "House_member",    10L,                     "10 or more",
                    "dob",     NA,                  "date of brith",
              "age_quota",     NA,                      "age_quota",
              "age_quota",     1L,                          "10-14",
              "age_quota",     2L,                          "15-19",
              "age_quota",     3L,                          "20-29",
              "age_quota",     4L,                          "30-39",
              "age_quota",     5L,                          "40-49",
              "age_quota",     6L,                          "50-70",
              "age_quota",     7L,                           "70 +",
                   "work",     NA,        "what is your occupation?",
                   "work",     1L,                      "full time",
                   "work",     2L,                      "part time",
                   "work",     3L,                        "retired",
                   "work",     4L,                        "student",
                   "work",     5L,                      "housewife",
                   "work",     6L,                     "unemployed",
                   "work",     7L,                          "other",
                   "work",     8L,                   "kid under 15",
                    "sex",     NA,                        "gender?",
                    "sex",     1L,                            "Man",
                    "sex",     2L,                          "Woman",
                    "pss",     NA,       "How often do you use PS?",
                    "pss",     1L,                          "Daily",
                    "pss",     2L,         "several times per week",
                    "pss",     3L,                  "once per week",
                    "pss",     4L,         "several time per month",
                    "pss",     5L,                          "Rarly"
           )
```

I am wondering is there any way that I can combine these file together to have a one labelled dataframe like `SPSS`’s style format (dbl+lbl format). I know `labelled` package which can add a value label to a non labelled vector, like this example:

```
v <- labelled::labelled(c(1,2,2,2,3,9,1,3,2,NA), c(yes = 1, maybe = 2, no = 3))
```

I was hoping there is a better/faster way than adding label to each variable one by one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another `imap_dfc` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% imap_dfc(~{ 
                  label[label$variable==.y,c('label','value')] %>%
                  deframe() %>% # to named vector
                  haven::labelled(.x,.)
                 })

# A tibble: 10 x 7
          id  House_member       dob age_quota           work       sex                        pss
   <int+lbl>     <int+lbl> <int+lbl> <int+lbl>      <int+lbl> <dbl+lbl>                  <dbl+lbl>
 1         1 4 [4 persons]      1983 2 [15-19] 2 [part time]  1 [Man]   1 [Daily]                 
 2         2 1 [1 person]       1940 7 [70 +]  2 [part time]  1 [Man]   2 [several times per week]
 3         3 2 [2 persons]      1951 5 [40-49] 6 [unemployed] 1 [Man]   1 [Daily]                 
 4         4 4 [4 persons]      1965 2 [15-19] 2 [part time]  1 [Man]   4 [several time per month]
 5         5 3 [3 persons]      1965 2 [15-19] 3 [retired]    1 [Man]   1 [Daily]                 
 6         6 1 [1 person]       1951 3 [20-29] 1 [full time]  1 [Man]   3 [once per week]         
 7         7 1 [1 person]       1955 1 [10-14] 1 [full time]  1 [Man]   3 [once per week]         
 8         8 4 [4 persons]      1982 2 [15-19] 2 [part time]  2 [Woman] 5 [Rarly]                 
 9         9 2 [2 persons]      1990 2 [15-19] 4 [student]    2 [Woman] 3 [once per week]         
10        10 2 [2 persons]      1953 3 [20-29] 2 [part time]  2 [Woman] 4 [several time per month]
```

Used `tibble::deframe` and `haven::labelled` which are included in `tidyverse`

Speed comparison after replacing `filter`/`select` by direct access to `label`:

```
Waldi <- function() {
df %>% imap_dfc(~{ 
    label[label$variable==.y,c('label','value')] %>%
      deframe() %>% # to named vector
      haven::labelled(.x,.)})}

Waldi_old <- function() {   
    df %>% imap_dfc(~{ 
      label %>% filter(variable==.y) %>%
        select(label, value) %>%
        deframe() %>% # to named vector
        haven::labelled(.x,.)
    })}

#EDIT : Included TIC33() for-loop solution

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(TIC3(),Waldi(),Anil(),TIC1(),Waldi_old(),Sinh())
Unit: microseconds
        expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval   cld
      TIC3()   688.0   871.80   982.280   920.95  1005.55  1801.6   100 a    
     Waldi()  1345.5  1543.60  1804.758  1635.45  1893.75  4306.8   100  b   
      Anil()  4006.8  4476.65  5188.519  4862.95  5439.10 10163.6   100   c  
      TIC1()  3898.2  4278.80  5009.927  4774.95  5277.05 12916.2   100   c  
 Waldi_old() 18712.3 20091.75 21756.140 20609.35 22169.75 33359.8   100    d 
      Sinh() 22730.9 24093.45 25931.412 24946.00 26614.00 38735.3   100     e
```

Comment: you may use `imap_dfc` instead and drop last step of `bind_cols`

Answer (score 4):

Though not as fast as other answer proposed by @Waldi, yet this may be considered as an option due to use of minimum external packages.

Alternate without using `purrr::imap_*` & `tibble::deframe`, this may be done in `dplyr` only using `mutate(across(..` as shown below-

```
library(dplyr)
library(labelled)

df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~labelled::labelled(as.double(.), 
                                                  setNames(label$value[label$variable == cur_column()], 
                                                           label$label[label$variable == cur_column()])
                                                  )))


# A tibble: 10 x 7
          id  House_member       dob age_quota           work       sex                        pss
   <dbl+lbl>     <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>      <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>                  <dbl+lbl>
 1         1 4 [4 persons]      1983 2 [15-19] 2 [part time]  1 [Man]   1 [Daily]                 
 2         2 1 [1 person]       1940 7 [70 +]  2 [part time]  1 [Man]   2 [several times per week]
 3         3 2 [2 persons]      1951 5 [40-49] 6 [unemployed] 1 [Man]   1 [Daily]                 
 4         4 4 [4 persons]      1965 2 [15-19] 2 [part time]  1 [Man]   4 [several time per month]
 5         5 3 [3 persons]      1965 2 [15-19] 3 [retired]    1 [Man]   1 [Daily]                 
 6         6 1 [1 person]       1951 3 [20-29] 1 [full time]  1 [Man]   3 [once per week]         
 7         7 1 [1 person]       1955 1 [10-14] 1 [full time]  1 [Man]   3 [once per week]         
 8         8 4 [4 persons]      1982 2 [15-19] 2 [part time]  2 [Woman] 5 [Rarly]                 
 9         9 2 [2 persons]      1990 2 [15-19] 4 [student]    2 [Woman] 3 [once per week]         
10        10 2 [2 persons]      1953 3 [20-29] 2 [part time]  2 [Woman] 4 [several time per month]
```

As noticed, in comments, you required output columns as `dbl + lbl` therefore first argument has been used as `as.double(.)` instead of just `.` in which the output will be `int + lbl` when input cols are of `integer` type.

Comment: Very good answer and easy to understand, upvoted it already! Actually you can improve it a bit if you can do some preprocessing on `label`, e.g., omitting rows with `NA`, which shrinks `label` and could be a bit faster. You can see the benchmarking in my answer.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, thanks for your suggestion.  It means a lot when stalwarts like you appreciate.  :)  Actually, I didn't shrink NA labels intentionally, as you can see from `label` data that actually some NA values are also labelled like NAs in `House_member` & `work`.  In this particular case, df has no NAs so it work faster.  Removing NA labels may, therefore not a thing as expected by OP.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Depends on how OP wants it :)

Comment: @AnilGoyal, see my update, when it goes on speed every detail counts, and use of filter seemed neat but wasn't an efficient idea on my side

Answer (score 4):

Here are some variants to the answer by [@AnilGoyal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67556661/12158757). It seems `for` loop (see `TIC3()`) provides nice speed.

- Variant1

```
TIC1 <- function() {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      across(everything(), ~ labelled(
        .,
        with(label, setNames(value, label)[variable == cur_column()])
      ))
    )
}
```

- Variant 2 (If you don't want `NA` being labelled)

```
TIC2 <- function() {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      across(
        with(label, unique(variable[!is.na(value)])),
        ~ labelled(
          .,
          with(label, setNames(value, label)[variable == cur_column()])
        )
      )
    )
}
```

- Variant 3 (`for` loop version of `TIC1()`)

```
TIC3 <- function() {
  nms <- names(df)
  for (k in nms[nms %in% label$variable]) {
    df[[k]] <- labelled(df[[k]], with(label, setNames(value, label)[variable == k]))
  }
  df
}
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
TIC1 <- function() {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      across(everything(), ~ labelled(
        .,
        with(label, setNames(value, label)[variable == cur_column()])
      ))
    )
}

TIC2 <- function() {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      across(
        with(label, unique(variable[!is.na(value)])),
        ~ labelled(
          .,
          with(label, setNames(value, label)[variable == cur_column()])
        )
      )
    )
}

TIC3 <- function() {
  nms <- names(df)
  for (k in nms[nms %in% label$variable]) {
    df[[k]] <- labelled(df[[k]], with(label, setNames(value, label)[variable == k]))
  }
  df
}


Waldi1 <- function() {
  df %>% imap_dfc(~ {
    label %>%
      filter(variable == .y) %>%
      select(label, value) %>%
      deframe() %>%
      # to named vector
      haven::labelled(.x, .)
  })
}

Waldi2 <- function() {
  df %>% imap_dfc(~ {
    label[label$variable == .y, c("label", "value")] %>%
      deframe() %>% # to named vector
      haven::labelled(.x, .)
  })
}

Anil <- function() {
  df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ labelled::labelled(
      as.double(.),
      setNames(
        label$value[label$variable == cur_column()],
        label$label[label$variable == cur_column()]
      )
    )))
}

custom_function <- function(value, col_name) {
  matching_vairable <- label %>%
    filter(variable == col_name & !is.na(value)) %>%
    select(label, value)
  column_data <- tibble(!!sym(col_name) := value)
  if (nrow(matching_vairable) > 0) {
    column_data[[1]] <- labelled::labelled(
      column_data[[1]],
      tibble::deframe(matching_vairable)
    )
  }
  column_data
}

Sinh <- function(x) {
  imap_dfc(df, .f = custom_function)
}

microbenchmark(
  Waldi1(),
  Waldi2(),
  Anil(),
  Sinh(),
  TIC1(),
  TIC2(),
  TIC3(),
  unit = "relative"
)
```

gives

```
Unit: relative
     expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
 Waldi1() 17.540613 17.359550 17.019266 17.238594 18.502584  4.7788575   100
 Waldi2()  1.355634  1.350547  1.338517  1.352509  1.342408  0.7033271   100
   Anil()  3.996836  4.011826  3.902559  4.029819  3.937232  1.2877871   100
   Sinh() 20.756122 20.595253 20.637410 20.452746 21.484992 13.0362139   100
   TIC1()  3.617278  3.617310  3.480283  3.609973  3.526703  1.0682179   100
   TIC2()  3.315545  3.384422  3.282862  3.389645  3.325616  1.0474304   100
   TIC3()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.0000000   100
```

Comment: Upvoted.  Your suggestion in TIC2 is really good

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding, see my update, when it goes on speed every detail counts, and use of filter seemed neat but wasn't an efficient idea on my side

Comment: @Waldi Yes, `filter` is not that efficient and it seems we underestimated the speed of `for` loops, you can see `TIC3()` in my updated answer.

Comment: Nice breach to the no `for loop` paradigm! Would have upvoted twice if I could ;-)

Comment: Excellent usage of for loop here.  Couldn't agree more on Waldi on upvoting twice.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `purrr::imap_dfc`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# custom function for taking the column data and column name and reformat the values using factor
custom_function <- function(value, col_name) { 
  matching_vairable <- label %>%
    filter(variable == col_name & !is.na(value)) %>%
    select(label, value)
  column_data <- tibble(!!sym(col_name) := value)
  if (nrow(matching_vairable) > 0) {
    column_data[[1]] <- labelled::labelled(column_data[[1]],
      tibble::deframe(matching_vairable))
  }
  column_data
}

new_df <- imap_dfc(df, .f = custom_function)
```

**Output**

```r
new_df
#> # A tibble: 10 x 7
#>       id  House_member   dob age_quota         work      sex                 pss
#>    <int>     <int+lbl> <int> <int+lbl>    <int+lbl> <dbl+lb>           <dbl+lbl>
#>  1     1 4 [4 persons]  1983 2 [15-19] 2 [part tim… 1 [Man]  1 [Daily]          
#>  2     2 1 [1 person]   1940 7 [70 +]  2 [part tim… 1 [Man]  2 [several times p…
#>  3     3 2 [2 persons]  1951 5 [40-49] 6 [unemploy… 1 [Man]  1 [Daily]          
#>  4     4 4 [4 persons]  1965 2 [15-19] 2 [part tim… 1 [Man]  4 [several time pe…
#>  5     5 3 [3 persons]  1965 2 [15-19] 3 [retired]  1 [Man]  1 [Daily]          
#>  6     6 1 [1 person]   1951 3 [20-29] 1 [full tim… 1 [Man]  3 [once per week]  
#>  7     7 1 [1 person]   1955 1 [10-14] 1 [full tim… 1 [Man]  3 [once per week]  
#>  8     8 4 [4 persons]  1982 2 [15-19] 2 [part tim… 2 [Woma… 5 [Rarly]          
#>  9     9 2 [2 persons]  1990 2 [15-19] 4 [student]  2 [Woma… 3 [once per week]  
#> 10    10 2 [2 persons]  1953 3 [20-29] 2 [part tim… 2 [Woma… 4 [several time pe…

new_df %>% pull(House_member)
#> <labelled<integer>[10]>
#>  [1] 4 1 2 4 3 1 1 4 2 2
#> 
#> Labels:
#>  value      label
#>      1   1 person
#>      2  2 persons
#>      3  3 persons
#>      4  4 persons
#>      5  5 persons
#>      6  6 persons
#>      7  7 persons
#>      8  8 persons
#>      9  9 persons
#>     10 10 or more
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way to get `dbl+lbl`  variable type after combining two files not `factor` type. `dbl+lbl` type still shows 4,1 ,2,4 for House_member but if we run `final_df%>% pull(House_member)` you will get variable labels like 1persons,2 persons,3 persons etc

Comment: I updated the answers to do it as you mentioned.